# How to tell users about new updates?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native

I have a React Native app with firebase for backend,

And now I'm in the last part to release it, 
But I have a question, after releasing my app I will add some updates or something and I want to ensure every user updates, so should I implement a modal that appears after adding some updates to my app and publishing it to stores

So I just thought if I made a boolean item if I add updates just change it to True and in my code if that true modal appeared else hidden it!

So that's a nice way to go with it?

Or can firebase help me in this case to tells any new things I do "I don't send to them push notifications if u want to tell me that"

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “I don't send to [them?] push notifications if u want to tell me that”?

Comment: I can’t vouch for it, but there’s a [React Native Siren](https://github.com/GantMan/react-native-siren) port of the popular [Siren for iOS](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren).

Comment: Hey @Rob I meant a normal notification something like [this](https://www.progressioapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/push_notif.jpg)

Comment: That looks like simple push notification. So, just keep track of what version users have been using (e.g. we store app version number during login) and do a push notification for anyone who hasn’t logged in the new version. FWIW, this seems like an excellent way to piss off your users and/or get them to disable notifications for your app. (I delete apps for less. Lol.) I think it’s much better to tell them when they go to the app, and delineate between the “you might want to” scenario and the “you must” scenario.

Comment: Hmm, sounds great thank you Rob, I will think in it again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tell your user about new update when they open the app, You can use `Firebase Remote Config` with needed keys like `latestVersion`, `forceUpdate`, `releaseNotes`, etc and show dialog in your app

[image: like this]].

[Demo Project](https://github.com/NAndroidEx/Remote-Config-App-Update-Dialog)

Comment: have you any example?

Comment: @OliverD I can prepare it in some time, will update you here for the same.

Comment: @OliverD I'm having some priority project work to do at this time, till then you can look into [this example](https://proandroiddev.com/firebase-remote-config-on-android-55a27f578505). Will update you here with example once I got some time(2-3 days). Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: thank you for your time, i will check it out, I think it's for Android Not for both (iOS, Android), So no way to handle it in react native especially?

Comment: yeah, i have prepared it for android only. but you'll easily find way to do in react also once understand it.